# Best way to create exclusive checkbox group QML

Tags: qt, qml

QML QtQuickControls provides a way to create an ExclusiveGroup of checkboxes however I don't like the appearance of the QtQuickControls so I want to create my own set of controls. I would like to know how to replicate the functionality of ExclusiveGroup on my own controls.

Answer (score 2):

> however I don't like the appearance of the QtQuickControls

Then use the `CheckBoxStyle` to design the visual appearance whilst keeping the existing behaviour.  Don't reinvent the wheel when you don't have to.